# Javascript function not doing anything with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

So, I have wrote the following code to calculate the BMI. The problem I'm facing is that my javascript function does not work. I even tried by inserting a sample text(commented in the code) for testing using  javascript, but that's not working. Can someone help me identify the problem?

```html
<h2>Welcome to BMI calculator</h2>
<h4>Please fill in the required data.</h4>

<form name="bmiform">
  <fieldset style="width:280px;">
    <legend>
      BMI CALCULATOR
    </legend>

    Name:
    <input type="text" value="" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>Height:
    <input type="text" value="" name="height">Meters
    <br>
    <br>Weight:
    <input type="text" value="" name="weight">Kilograms
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="BMIcalc(document.bmiform.weight.value,document.bmiform.height.value)">

  </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <br>
  <br>Your BMI is: <b id="samples"></b>
  <!--Inner HTML does not inserts text in here-->

  <script>
    document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = "Testing purposes"; //This code does not work.
    function BMIcalc(parseFloat(weight), parseFloat(height)) {
      var bmi = (weight / (height * height));
      document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = bmi;
    }
  </script>

  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
      <th>
        BMI
      </th>
      <th>
        Weight Status
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Below 18.5
      </td>
      <td>
        Underweight
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        18.5-24.9
      </td>
      <td>
        Normal
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        25.0-29.9
      </td>
      <td>
        Overweight
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        30.0 and above
      </td>
      <td>
        Obese
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would *at least* expect that you press the "tidy" button in the StackSnippet so that your code is properly indented.

Comment: Your code does not work because you have a syntax error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`. You would have seen this is if you looked at the console. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions to learn how to properly define functions.

Comment: I would suggest you learn how to use the Chrome Developer Tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a thing like this `function BMIcalc(parseFloat(weight), parseFloat(height))` in your function declaration.

It must be `function BMIcalc(weight, height)` And your parsefloat should be inside your function body or in function call.

Comment: Okay. But why does  document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = "Testing purposes";  fails to insert "testing purposes" in  <br>Your BMI is: <b id="samples"></b>.  Shouldn't it work automatically on page load as it defined outside the function and inside the <script></script>.

Comment: Because your wrong declaration causes a syntax error, so no code is executed at all, since the interpreter checks syntax before execution.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your function as follows, the `parseFloat` should be called within the function, you cannot call a function in a function declaration parameters like you are doing:

```
function BMIcalc(weight, height) {
  var bmi = (parseFloat(weight) / (parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(height)));
  document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = bmi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: 
1. I prefer not parse any value to `onclick`, so I move the retrieve into function `BMIcalc`.
2. you can't do any action to your parameter field, you have to parse or do something else in function.

```js
document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = "Testing purposes"; //This code does not work.
    function BMIcalc() {
      var weight = parseFloat(document.bmiform.weight.value);
      var height = parseFloat(document.bmiform.height.value);
      var bmi = (weight / (height * height));
      document.getElementById("samples").innerHTML = bmi;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Welcome to BMI calculator</h2>
<h4>Please fill in the required data.</h4>

<form name="bmiform">
  <fieldset style="width:280px;">
    <legend>
      BMI CALCULATOR
    </legend>

    Name:
    <input type="text" value="" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>Height:
    <input type="text" value="" name="height">Meters
    <br>
    <br>Weight:
    <input type="text" value="" name="weight">Kilograms
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="BMIcalc()">

  </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <br>
  <br>Your BMI is: <b id="samples"></b>
  <!--Inner HTML does not inserts text in here-->
  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
      <th>
        BMI
      </th>
      <th>
        Weight Status
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Below 18.5
      </td>
      <td>
        Underweight
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        18.5-24.9
      </td>
      <td>
        Normal
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        25.0-29.9
      </td>
      <td>
        Overweight
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        30.0 and above
      </td>
      <td>
        Obese
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```